# Floating Nodes Error in Simulation in ORCAD PSPICE

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrical, pspice, orcad, floating

Does anyone have any insight as to what exactly is wrong with my circuit on Orcad/PSPICE?

My name is in the project name so I blurred it out for obvious reasons
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, hence, I will try to answer here anyways.

Change the ground symbol. You should use parts from the PSPICE libraries where the ground symbol has the label **0** (zero voltage). Replace the present ground symbol with the **0/SOURCE** ground. 
Read more about it [here](http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE65/06-S/PSpice_Notes.pdf) and [here](https://www.pspice.com/incorrect-ground-symbol-may-result-floating-node-or-convergence-problems).